# Math concept map

Tags: concept-maps

I am dealing with some inner city kids who  are all over the place. I want to use a concept map to slowly develop their math skills in an organized manner. If anybody can point me to Math Concept maps something that is visual , that will be very helpful. Thanks much.

Good question, @ Tommi Brander ,@ Joe

The students are between the ages of 9-12 years. Ramsey county, Minnesota.

Comment: Welcome to the site! As explained in the preceding comment, it would be helpful to have some more details. You can add them via an [edit].

Comment: To the members voting to close - it would be kind to allow Jill 24 hours to clarify her question with the requested details. A bit of a grace period.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, thanks Joe just got back from volunteering as a judge for a highschool math competition...lot of driving and tried.

Comment: **FWIW**: I voted to close as "unclear" *after* the edit. The additional information (age 9-12, in MN) did not, in my estimation, provide sufficient detail so as to make this question tractable. I would still be interested to see a fleshed out version, though...

Comment: Khan Academy has a knowledge map.   A portion of it might be just what you are looking for.  You can find it at [https://www.khanacademy.org/exercisedashboard] (https://www.khanacademy.org/exercisedashboard)  There is a list of topics on the left side which you can scroll through.  Once you find a topic that interests you, click on it and you will be taken to that topic and see related topics connected to it.

Comment: @AmyB thanks Amy that is exactly what I was looking for. This will work.